# How to get dirtiness on a simple texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, texture-painting

Whenever i downloaded a texture it looks very simple like the image bellow[image]

so i want to add dirtiness like the image below[image]
I am using Photoshop to prepare my textures so somebody please tell me how to do it in Photoshop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello sir. This is a Blender forum. You'll find more luck on a specialized Photoshop forum. Good luck and happy Blendering.

Comment: @JachymMichal [blender.SE] is not a forum, it's a Stack Exchange Q & A site.  There is a subtle but definite difference.  While the question appears off-topic in its current form, it would be more useful to state that and how to fix it, or flag it as such.

Comment: @Merlin Thanks for explaining the difference. Next time I'll know what to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about image editing

Comment: Image editing? It is about texturing, and that is a blender task - unfortunately, many do not explore this aspect of Blender as a dedicated image texture editor/painter. The compositor and image editor combined with the 3d view texture paint mode makes for a stronger editor than most dedicated image editors imho.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend establishing a paint set up in Blender first on the model by painting details on the model in the 3d view using Texture Paint mode, and then take the saved image textures into Photoshop to further build on the initial block out. Here in the picture I have used a cloud texture on a texture paint brush set to multiply and Rake and Random for the stroke, and painted grunge burns on the areas where I cloned the image texture into my basic canvas texture.
[image]
One thing to note is that you can use Photoshop to paint in 3d view, so you might just try importing your model as .obj with your basic material and texture and then adding a layer in photoshop, doing your detail work there.